# Using 'send' on a before_save filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, before-save

I have a before_save filter called `:strip_whitespaces` on a Rails model like this

```
  before_save :strip_whitespaces
```

The `strip_whitespaces` filter is a private method which is defined in the following way:

```
private 
  def strip_whitespaces
    self.name = name.split.join(" ") if attribute_present?("name")
    self.description = description.split.join(" ") if attribute_present?("description")
    self.aliases = aliases.split.join(" ") if attribute_present?("aliases")
  end
```

How do I use ruby's send method to make this method DRY-er? This also helps once I have to add more fields to this filter.

I had something like this in mind but it does not work

```
  %W[name description aliases].each do |attr|
    self.send(attr) = self.send(attr).split.join(" ") if attribute_present?(attr)
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! A variant of this worked - [:name, :description, :aliases].each do |attr|
        self.send( "#{attr}=", self.send("#{attr}").split.join(" ") )
      end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd even be tempted split it into *two* private methods:

```
def strip_whitespaces
  %w(name description aliases).each do |attribute|
    strip_whitespace_from attribute
  end
end

def strip_whitespace_from(attr)
  send("#{attr}=", send(attr).split.join(" ")) if attribute_present?(attr)
end
```

Note that you don't need to do `self.send` - the `self` is implied - and also you don't need to do `send("#{attr}")` because that interpolation achieves nothing, you can just do `send(attr)`.

Comment: This is pretty cool!. Accepting your answer over mine since this is awesomer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer has a good description to the setter syntax on the `send` method of a ruby object - [How to set "programmatically"\"iteratively" each class object attribute to a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477062/how-to-set-programmatically-iteratively-each-class-object-attribute-to-a-val)

The problem in this particular case was solved by using the following code

```
def strip_whitespaces
  [:name, :description, :aliases].each do |attr|
    self.send( "#{attr}=", self.send("#{attr}").split.join(" ") ) if attribute_present?(attr)
  end
end
```

Here, the code gets the the current value of the attribute `self.send("#{attr}")` first, strips off white-spaces, and then sets it to attribute through `"#{attr}="` setter. `attribute_present?(attr)` is a method on the `ActiveRecord::Base` class which returns false if the atribute is not present.